# Separating paragraphs in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with paragraphs separated by 2 empty lines in unix. I want to copy paragraphs after searching for a word to another file. I am able to copy paragraphs but the paragraphs separators are not present so it is coming as on continuous para.
My command to separate para:

```
awk -v RS= '/Testing/' file>>file2
```

Now I am getting:

```
Testing 
case1
Testing
case2
```

What I need to get

```
Testing 
case1


Testing
case2
```

Comment: can you post a fragment of your initial file with paragraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `ORS (Output Record Separator)` as `\n\n` in `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= '/Testing/' ORS='\n\n' file
```

Default value of `ORS` is `\n`. But, Paragraph needs `\n\n`.

Comment: I want my paragraphs in output file to be separted by 2 empty lines

Comment: @codehacker, Use: `awk -v RS= '/Testing/' ORS='\n\n\n' file > file.out`

Comment: @codehacker, Glad it worked for you. If this answer helped to solve your problem consider accepting by clicking tick mark on left side of an answer.